# MGF of a sum of r.variables

Tags: probability

Suppouse $X_1,X_2,...X_N$ are independent having exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and $N$ has a poisson($\lambda$) distribution and is independant pf the $X_i$.

1) determining the mgf of $S_N=X_1+...+X_N$:

my sol. since $X_i$'s are independent, the mgf of their sum is the product of their respective mgfs so $M_{S_N}(t)=(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t})^N$.

2)Find the mean.

my sol. since $M_{S_N}(t)=M_Z(t)$ where $Z$~$gamma(N,\lambda)$, they have the same distribution so the mean is N.

3) Find the distribution of $Y=\sum_{i=1}^N2(\lambda)X_i$ and identify it.

my sol. by theorem, since the $X_i$ are independant, $M_Y(t)=(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-2\lambda t})^N$ But im not sure what distribution this corresponds to

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For (3), $M_Y(t) = \left ( \frac{1}{1-2t} \right )^N = \left(1 - 2t \right ) ^{-N}$ is the moment generating function for a Gamma Distribution, $\Gamma(k,\theta)$, with parameters $k = N$ and $\theta = 2$ per the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples) on moment generating functions.